# Stop Google OAuth reprompting for permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, simplemembership

I have Google authentication working in my app through OAuthWebSecurity. Every time I login, Google re-prompts for permissions. **How can I prevent Google from re-prompting every time?**

I am currently using a custom OpenIdClient  to get extra data from Google ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx)), but this also happens with the default client.

```
internal static class AuthConfig
{
    public static void RegisterOpenAuth(ConfigurationWrapper configuration)
    {
        //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient(); // using this has the exact same problem as my custom code
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new GoogleCustomClient(), "Google", null);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents Google OpenID client.
/// </summary>
public class GoogleCustomClient : OpenIdClient
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public GoogleCustomClient()
        : base("google", WellKnownProviders.Google)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the extra data obtained from the response message when authentication is successful.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">
    /// The response message. 
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>A dictionary of profile data; or null if no data is available.</returns>
    protected override Dictionary<string, string> GetExtraData(IAuthenticationResponse response)
    {
        var fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
        if (fetchResponse == null) return null;

        var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"email", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)},
            {"country", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.HomeAddress.Country)},
            {"firstName", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First)},
            {"lastName", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last)}
        };

        return extraData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called just before the authentication request is sent to service provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">
    /// The request. 
    /// </param>
    protected override void OnBeforeSendingAuthenticationRequest(IAuthenticationRequest request)
    {
        // Attribute Exchange extensions
        var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.HomeAddress.Country);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);

        request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Its asking for authentication again probably because you aren't using your refresh token to get a new access token.  I would recommend using the Google's dot net client lib its much easer. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/

Comment: @DaImTo Switching to Google's APIs are out of the question, as I am using SimpleMembership to unify this for many providers (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft and Yahoo).

Comment: I have waited countless hours on and off over the last two years trying to get OAuthWebSecurity working with Google oauth2.  If you get it to work please share the code :)